# JUnit 5 parameterized test: Using CSVFileSource with Enclosed.Class

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am trying to run parameterized and non parameterized test cases in the same class using

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
```

But somehow tests are not running. I have tried the `csvFileSource` without `Enclosed` class and it works fine. This is how my test class skeleton looks like: (Please help)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class MyTest {
   static class Base{
   }

   @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
   public static class ParameterizedTests extends Base {
       @ParameterizedTest(name = "testString:{0}")
       @CsvFileSource(resources = "testCases.csv")
       public void test(String testString) {
          ....
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `@RunWith` is an annotation from JUnit 4. You don't need it when running JUnit Jupiter's `@ParameterizedTest`. See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests for details.

Next, *only non-static nested classes (i.e. inner classes) can serve as `@Nested` test classes.* See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested for details and reasoning.

Minimal working example:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

class MyTest {

  class Base {}

  @Nested
  class ParameterizedTests extends Base {
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "testString:{0}")
    @ValueSource(strings = "testCases.csv")
    void test(String testString) {
      System.out.println(testString);
    }
  }
}
```